# rosserial_arduino setup problem

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im installing Arduino IDE Setup following the steps

cd /src
git clone https://github(dot)com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git
cd 
catkin_make
catkin_make install
source /install/setup.bash

This suppose to create a ros_lib library in the /install directory, but it doesn't.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65361/rosserial_arduino-setup-problem/) by [coughsyrup](https://answers.ros.org/users/4962/coughsyrup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ros_lib should be installed in your Arduino "sketchbook/libraries".  To install the ros_lib in the sketchbook use `ros rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py <sketchbook>/libraries/`  .  You will have to make the libraries folder and the sketchbook should automatically be generated in the home directory after the Arduino IDE is opened once.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4